# Magento extension install - Dependancy error

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

I am installing an extension I have written and published to the Magento Marketplace, but I get an error when installing from the store that makes no sense.

> Check Component Dependency
>
> We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail
>
> Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - The requested package magento/product-community-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name. Problem
>   2
>   - Installation request for oddware/shipsterconnect 100.1.36 -> satisfiable by oddware/shipsterconnect[100.1.36].
>   - oddware/shipsterconnect 100.1.36 requires magento/module-sales 100.1.* -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>   - A typo in the package name
>   - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>   details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for
>   further common problems.
>
> For additional assistance, see component dependency help .

I don't understand what the error about the community module is at all, it makes no sense and is not in my composer.json.  And the module-sales makes even less sense, as that module is installed;

"magento/module-sales   Magento_Sales   100.1.8"

And this is the composer.json in my extension;

```
{
  "name": "oddware/shipsterconnect",
  "description": "Oddware module for exporting to Shipster",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.0|~6.0|~7.0",
    "magento/module-sales": "~100.0|~101.0",
    "magento/module-shipping": "~100.0",
    "magento/module-backend": "~100.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "100.1.37",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
  ],
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "OddWare\\ShipsterConnect\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
  }
],
```

in your module's composer should do the job.

Comment: Removed my previous comment, was a local configuration issue I fixed.  Adding this did not fix it unfortunately.

Comment: Turns out this needed adding to the composer.json that was part of my Magento install.  I'm not sure why, it is in the package file, but I think it might be related to authenticating to the repo.  If you update I'll mark as answer!